Issue with Google Sign-In on Android TV using CredentialManager and AuthorizationClient
I'm using CredentialManager and AuthorizationClient for Google sign-in in my app. While the sign-in process works as expected on Android phones, it fails on Android TV. Specifically, on Android TV, the sign-in intent automatically cancels, returning Activity.RESULT_CANCELED with null data. On phones, however, the same code returns Activity.RESULT_OK with valid data when the sign-in is confirmed.
Consider the code I am using,
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
 private val credentialManager = CredentialManager.create(this)
 private val credential = mutableStateOf<Credential?>(null)
 private val googleIdTokenCredential = mutableStateOf<GoogleIdTokenCredential?>(null)
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  val authorizationRequest = AuthorizationRequest.Builder()
   .requestOfflineAccess(getString(R.string.server_client_id),true)
   .setRequestedScopes(listOf(Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"),
    Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"),
    Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly"),
    Scope("openid")))
   .build()
  val authorizationLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()){
   activityResult ->
    when(activityResult.resultCode) {
     Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
      val auth = Identity.getAuthorizationClient(this)
       .getAuthorizationResultFromIntent(activityResult.data)
      setContent{
       SignInSuccess()
     }}
     Activity.RESULT_CANCELED -> {
      Log.d("GoogleId", "User cancelled sign-in: $activityResult")
     }
     else -> Log.d("GoogleId","resultcode: ${activityResult.resultCode}")
  }}
  setContent {
   MyApplicationTheme {
    Homepage(onClick = {signIn(authorizationLauncher, authorizationRequest)})
 }}}

 private fun signIn(authorizationLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest>,authorizationRequest: AuthorizationRequest) {
  if(isNetworkAvailable(this)) {
   val rawNonce = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
   val bytes = rawNonce.toByteArray()
   val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
   val digest = md.digest(bytes)
   val hashedNonce = digest.fold(""){str, it -> str + "%02x".format(it)}
   val signInWithGoogleOption: GetSignInWithGoogleOption = GetSignInWithGoogleOption.Builder(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
    .setNonce(hashedNonce)
    .build()
   val request: GetCredentialRequest = GetCredentialRequest.Builder()
    .addCredentialOption(signInWithGoogleOption)
    .build()
   lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
    try{
     val result = credentialManager.getCredential(this@MainActivity,request)
     credential.value = result.credential
     when(credential.value){
      is CustomCredential -> {
       if(credential.value!!.type == GoogleIdTokenCredential.TYPE_GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN_CREDENTIAL){
        googleIdTokenCredential.value = GoogleIdTokenCredential.createFrom(credential.value!!.data)
        Identity.getAuthorizationClient(this@MainActivity)
         .authorize(authorizationRequest)
         .addOnSuccessListener { authorizationResult ->
          if (authorizationResult.hasResolution()) {
           authorizationResult.pendingIntent?.intentSender?.let { intentSender ->
            val intentSenderRequest = IntentSenderRequest.Builder(intentSender).build()
            authorizationLauncher.launch(intentSenderRequest)
          }}}
         .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
          Log.e("GoogleID","failure: ${exception.message}")
       }}}
      else -> Log.e("GoogleID","Unexpected type of credential")
    }} catch (e: GetCredentialException) {
     Log.e("GoogleID","CredentialException: ${e.message}")
    } catch (e: GoogleIdTokenParsingException) {
     Log.e("GoogleID","GoogleIdTokenParsingException: ${e.message}")
  }}}}}

It seems that the sign-in intent is not being handled correctly on Android TV. Can anyone help identifying why the intent is automatically canceling and how to resolve this problem.? Additionally, can CredentialManager be used for sign-in on Android TV, and are there any specific considerations or limitations for using it on this platform?

Sign-in using CredentialManager should work. Authorization, however, is not supported on TV platform.

What is the best method for implementing Google Sign-In to access Google APIs now that 'GoogleSignIn' is deprecated?

On Android mobile phones and tablets, the recommended APIs for Authorization is now provided by these Authorization APIs (see https://developers.google.com/identity/authorization/android). Authentication and Authorization are now separated from each other.

I'm developing an app specifically for Android TV and need to implement authorization to obtain a serverAuthCode. Previously, I used GoogleSignIn, which successfully retrieved the serverAuthCode, but since GoogleSignIn is now deprecated, I'm unsure of the best approach. As I'm new to this area, could you suggest an alternative method for authorization that would allow me to get the serverAuthCode?

What scopes were you asking for on TV?

I'm using the following scopes for my Android TV app:
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly' for read-only access to Google Photos.
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email' for access to the user's email address.
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile' for access to the user's basic profile information.
'openid' for OpenID Connect to authenticate the user.
Could you suggest an alternative method to obtain the serverAuthCode with these scopes now that GoogleSignIn is deprecated?

I am also interested in this. To only fetch the serverAuthToken. Did you find a way @SreelakshmiPP ? Thanks! My question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79208211
