Only receive ServerAuthToken with Credential Manager?
is it possible to only receive the serverAuthCode with the Credential Manager [1] in an Android App written in Java ?
Our backend expects only this information so it may make the request to Google to receive info about the user thats trying to login.
My current implementation is:
CredentialManager manager = CredentialManager.create(getApplicationContext());
            GetGoogleIdOption googleIdOption = new GetGoogleIdOption.Builder()
                    .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(true) // only existing google accounts, no "create new google account" screen
                    .setAutoSelectEnabled(true)
                    .setServerClientId("web_client_id")
                    .build();
            GetCredentialRequest request = new GetCredentialRequest.Builder()
                    .addCredentialOption(googleIdOption)
                    .build();

CredentialManagerCallback<GetCredentialResponse, GetCredentialException> credentialManagerCallback = new CredentialManagerCallback<GetCredentialResponse, GetCredentialException>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(GetCredentialResponse result) {
                    // result here has all the data of the user, like email, name

                    // wanted: only serverAuthToken to send over to the backend which is then makeing the google api request
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull GetCredentialException error) {
                    // handle error
                }
            };
            manager.getCredentialAsync(
                    _activity_instance,
                    request,
                    null,
                    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(),
                    credentialManagerCallback
            );

[1] https://developer.android.com/identity/sign-in/credential-manager

No, that is not possible. You can only receive an auth code if you use the Authorization APIs; Credential Manager is aimed at authentication and not authorization.

Thanks Mr. Naddaf. Is it possible someone from the Google team can add more examples to your linked page? Specially like an example to make the user chose their Google account. (I am having a hard time to understand which scope that would be and how to explain that the user)

You're welcome. Please elaborate on what you need exactly; you were asking what scopes you should request; that pretty much depends on what kind of access you want to have. For example if you want to access the user's drive, you would ask for Drive scope. In your case, what do you need access to?

My use-case is we have a webview application and want to give users access to the "Google Sign-In" button. Currently that works with the deprecated class like this: user clicks the webview button - javascript triggers native function in the Java application - native app triggers the "GoogleSignIn" class - eventually the user selects which Google account to use. I receive a serverAuthToken. That serverAuthToken among other things is sent to our backend. Our backend checks the Google API for user details (email, name and id) and proceeds to check if that user needs a new account (continue...)

(..continue) or link to an existing account (previously linked, or same email). So our backend uses the Google API before checking other things. Now with the CredentialManager this is all done in the App already - but I won't have data about the user (like access / refresh token), so I (the website) cannot "check" if that user is still account-linked or not.

Oh I forgot. After our backend is done checking we give information back to the Android app - which then deals with the response. (i.e reloads the webview, shows error message, ...)

One approach for you is to use the Authorization APIs, as was mentioned above, instead of the Credential Manager APIs. I am not sure how much information you need to have about a user but you can try these scopes: "openid", "email", "profile" in your AuthorizationRequest (using its Builder) and ask for offline-access. That will show an account selector if user is not already signed in (and if user is signed-in and you want to show the account picker, you can call the "signOut()" to sign the user out first). Response will have an access token and an auth code. Hope that answers your question.

Yes, thats exactly what I needed. Can the Google team add this to the examples? :)

That is not a common use case though. To get openid+email+profile data, which is the common "authentication" flow, it is recommended to use the Authentication APIs which returns an ID Token, adequate for almost all authentication purposes. In your case, you wanted to get an auth code and that is why you had to use the other flow, and as I mentioned, it is rare to need that for those scopes, as part of authentication, hence not a use case that would warrant an explicit sample/example.

Ok I understand and try to find a workaround that works for us. Thank you for your time.

Just to confirm, I thought the earlier recommendation on using the Authorization APIs did work for you, was that not the case? Thanks.

On the Android App (Java) side I have not tried the new Authorization suggestion yet. (Like shown here https://developers.google.com/identity/authorization/android)
However, the current in-production solution is the legacy solution (which wasnt legacy when I implemented it (I think ^^)): https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/legacy-sign-in and https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth
